# Using WideCharToMultiByte with Codepage 1258 (Vietnamese)

Tags: winapi, unicode, localization

I am trying to convert a wide char string to Vietnamese ANSI (CP 1258), and for some reason half of the diacritics are wrong. I did some research and unearthed this: http://www.siao2.com/2005/04/19/409566.aspx and this: http://www.siao2.com/2005/08/27/457224.aspx, which kind of confirm my suspicion that this is a special case. I added the **WC_COMPOSITECHECK** flag, but it does not help.

What I don't understand is why it is different from Thai, which also has this kind of multilayered diacritics. Thai worked just fine for me. Is there any kind of secret handshake I must use?

Comment: Yes, it is special, it is a multi-byte encoding.  One letter can produce two bytes when converted.  Look for codes marked with a white background in this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1258

Comment: Thanks, Hans. Yes, I got that (although so is Thai, and it works without a hitch). 

Any idea how I prod it in the right direction? Or nobody knows how?

Comment: What's the *real* problem?  Any program that advertizes knowing how to handle the Vietnamese code page should not have a problem with it.  If it doesn't then there's preciously little you can do about it if you don't have its source code.

Comment: Well, the program in question is Windows API. In my case, the characters that come through as question marks are those with multiple diacritics. Single diacritics are fine. Is there any kind of preprocessing that can be done on the Unicode string to replace these characters with something that WideCharToMultByte can digest properly? Again, this is the first time I saw WideCharToMultiByte not working properly.

Comment: The Windows API is Unicode at its core.  Translating to a code page like 1259 and back to Unicode is indeed going to be disappointing, documented behavior.  The reason you have to do this is quite unclear.

Comment: So far it was only disappointing for Vietnamese. I tried everything else - Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, Japanese, Thai, Hebrew, Arabic. It worked without a hitch! I did not expect to hit a snag with an ISO-8859 character set. The reason I have to do this is that I must keep my data ANSI compatible as my middleware may be used with both Unicode and non-Unicode applications. I may say that it only supports Unicode Vietnamese but that's silly considering the fact that there is a Vietnamese codepage and that, again, there was never a problem with more complex scripts.

Comment: OK, I'll try to break this deadlock, Hans. Suppose I manually find a set of characters in a particular Unicode range (e.g. those with multiple diacritics), then substitute them by two characters: say, Unicode equivalents of 227 and 242. Will that silly function be able to convert these to 227 and 242 or it will meddle to break everything?

Comment: Interesting. I tried to force a decomposed form D (ệ into ệ), and it was able to read and re-assemble the first two characters (that is, e and the dot). The third one became a question mark. Same when I tried 2 + 1 combination. Apparently, the problem is on the assembly side, not the decomposition.

Comment: I think I solved it (kinda). The original character was a Unicode for "e with circumflex and combining dot". Breaking it into e, combining dot, circumflex did not make any difference. However, looking at the Wikipedia article, I saw that actually there is no such character as e with dot, but there is e with circumflex. So when I broke it into e with circumflex + combining dot, it worked. I suppose I need to pre-process the input. Thank me very much.

Comment: Here is the solution: http://digitalsonata.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/workaround-for-conversion-of-unicode.html